# Move elements from std::multiset

Tags: c++11, constants, move, multiset

Is there anyway to move an element out of a std::multiset?

Since C++11 std::multiset::iterator is defined as a const bidirectional_iterator. I understand the reasoning is for keeping the elements sorted, but there seems to be no way to remove and then modify move only objects.

Comment: like [extract](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/extract) but for c++11 ?

Comment: Ahh, yes, too bad it is C++17.

Comment: probably an oversight in c++11, not sure you have any alternative =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with std::multiset, though it should be doable with Boost's multi_index_container. It has a modify() method that takes an iterator and an updater functor. In that functor you should be able to move the value away.

For details, see Boost multi_index [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating).